# How to Multiply the count value with 5

Tags: mongodb-query

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
)
```

Suppose the output of count is 20. i want to multiply this count value (20) with 5. result should be 100 in another row total : count*5.